# What does minus and plus notations do on string in c++

Tags: c++, string

I am asking about the job of minus and plus notation on string , in this situation specifically :

```
Solver(string s) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        grid[i] = (int) (s[i] - '0'); // the minus here will remove 0's of string or not ?
    }
}

int main() {
    Solver ss(
            (string) "850002400" + // the plus here will combine all strings together like Java or not ?
            (string) "720000009" +
            (string) "004000000" +
            (string) "000107002" +
            (string) "305000900" +
            (string) "040000000" +
            (string) "000080070" +
            (string) "017000000" +
            (string) "000036040"
            );
}
```

Comment: Not that `-` is not being applied to string but on a character

Comment: Why don't you run this and check result by yourself ?

Comment: Actually, this is not a [mre], obviously, `Solver` is a class, but class definition and especially definition of `grid` is missing. While this information is not relevant for current question (thus you don't need to modify), you might keep an eye on in your next question, maybe next time we'll need complete information...

Comment: [ASCII Table and Description](http://www.asciitable.com/) -- what would subtracting `'0'` from `'9'` leave you? (hint: the integer value of the ASCII digit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`operator+` for string concatenates them – as you discovered already. But there's no `operator-` for strings!

Have a close look, you are not subtracting from the string (`s - '0'`), but from the character `s[i]`. This won't remove the character from the string, but instead calculate a new value based on the character's value minus the value of zero character (which has a value of 48, in ASCII and compatible, at least – not the value null!). As digits are guaranteed to be contiguous by C++ standard (just like in C as well), you can reliably calculate decimal digits from characters that way.

This works for bases smaller than 10, too, but not larger ones, as next characters used for representation don't follow the decimal digits directly (and you might have to distinguish upper and lower case letters).

Side note: You don't need the cast to int: as type `char` is smaller in size than `int`, both operands will be promoted to int implicitly, so actually the calculation is done in `int` anyway and the result remains `int`...

Comment: Interesting fun fact: Old Cray systems had `char`s that were the same size as `int`s. Before my time fortunately. Before C++, too, but would still be legal.

Comment: @user4581301 Actually, there's even a recent DSP produced by TI (don't remember model name any more, though) that has the same issue (CHAR_BIT = 16, sizeof(char) = sizeof(short) = sizeof(int)). But even if sizes are the same, promotion to int still occurs (or unsigned int *then*, if char is unsigned!).

Comment: The weird ol' days never really go away, do they?

Answer (score 0):

Subtracting '0' from any character of digit will return the integer value of that digit.

```c
char seven = '7';
int value = (int)(seven - '0');
cout<<value<<endl;
```

Output:

```
7
```

In your example `-` was used to convert a character grid(1D) to integer grid(1D).

On the other hand, `+` sign between two or more `string` type data represent concatenation of string.

```c
string s =  "abc" +  "def";
cout<<s<<endl;
```

Output:

```
abcdef
```

Comment: please modify the answer to include the behavior of `+` on string as well

Comment: Why print in your first and cout in your second example?

Comment: @nada to explicitly show that value is an integer. Anyway I've edited.

Answer (score 0):

string - C++ Reference
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

As is said in link above, the operator+ means "Concatenate strings".
If you want to CLIP the string,  you can use the s.substr() function.

```
grid[i] = (int) (s[i] - '0')
```

the the minus in code means transform the 'char' to 'int'. For example,

```
string s="425";
char c = s[0];     //c='4';
int value = c-'0'; //value=4 it is a number
```

It is not the function of string, just a utilization of ASCII.
The function stoi(s[i]) can realize the same thing.